# Elements floating over each other even though they're blocks?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So front-end design isn't really my forte...

I'm attempting to have every post/my main header/logo take up 100% by 100% which works. But I'm also trying to have certain elements positioned within the parent element, also which I have done, but when the site gets resized down the elements tend to just float over on top of one another.

Is there a way I can go about making it so each element acts as a block to prevent the float?

```css
 body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 }

 /* Article/Content */
 div.article {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
 }
 div.article p {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 }
 div.article div.datetime {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
 }
 .hookers {
  vertical-align: middle;
     font-size: 700%;
     color:#CFD8DC;
     letter-spacing: -2px;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-shadow: 1px 1px #78909C,2px 2px #78909C,3px 3px #78909C,4px 4px #78909C,5px 5px #78909C,6px 6px #78909C,7px 7px #78909C,8px 8px #78909C,9px 9px #78909C,10px 10px #78909C;
 }

 /* Misc */
 .noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
 }
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div class="header article">
 <span class="hookers noselect">WELCOME</span>
</div>

<div class="article">
  <div class="datetime">Posted on <?= date('Y-m-d'); ?> at <?= time(); ?></div>
  <p>The path of the righteous man is beset on all sides by the iniquities of the selfish and the tyranny of evil men. Blessed is he who, in the name of charity and good will, shepherds the weak through the valley of darkness, for he is truly his brother's keeper and the finder of lost children. And I will strike down upon thee with great vengeance and furious anger those who would attempt to poison and destroy My brothers. And you will know My name is the Lord when I lay My vengeance upon thee.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: position:absolute, takes element of the flux. Why do you use position here ? (.datetime)

Comment: @GCyrillus I use position there to put the date at the top left and I did want to put a thing on the bottom right too, do you think maybe I should put a min-height on the article and call it a day?

Answer (score 0):

On div.article, set it to `position: absolute;`
Then set the child blocks to `position:relative;`.

Finally, position the block inside the div using top, bottom, left and right. The blocks will position relative to the absolutely positioned parent container.

**CSS:**

```
body {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

/* Article/Content */
div.article {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
}
div.article p {
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
div.article, div.datetime {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    position: relative;

    display: inline-block;
}
.hookers {
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 700%;
    color:#CFD8DC;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #78909C,2px 2px #78909C,3px 3px #78909C,4px 4px #78909C,5px 5px #78909C,6px 6px #78909C,7px 7px #78909C,8px 8px #78909C,9px 9px #78909C,10px 10px #78909C;
}

/* Misc */
.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div class="header ">
    <span class="hookers noselect">WELCOME</span>
</div>

<div class="article">
        <div class="datetime">Posted on <?= date('Y-m-d'); ?> at <?= time(); ?></div>
        <p>The path of the righteous man is beset on all sides by the iniquities of the selfish and the tyranny of evil men. Blessed is he who, in the name of charity and good will, shepherds the weak through the valley of darkness, for he is truly his brother's keeper and the finder of lost children. And I will strike down upon thee with great vengeance and furious anger those who would attempt to poison and destroy My brothers. And you will know My name is the Lord when I lay My vengeance upon thee.</p>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/gemlarin/9L4st2gn/)

Comment: this works per element but how come when I try to make .hookers and the paragraph vertical-align to middle it just stays at the top? Is there a way around that or can I only have one or the other? Thanks Mate

Comment: Vertical-align does not work with positioning when it is not part of either a Table or that specific flex box.  If you are using divs for specific elements, you have to set you v-align either using margins and padding or by relative positioning.